# Do Fire Walkers damage enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii

The new [Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers) leave a trail of fire behind you.

[image: Fire Walkers tooltip says "Burn the ground you walk on."]

Does this fire damages enemies it touches?  If so, how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it does damage enemies! There's some information on the forum about this. [Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6397900167) is someone who knows a bit more. Look at post #2

He says the damage ticks at around 2500-5500. He also mentions it can hit objects such as barrels to open them. I have no idea if the damage is based off weapon damage or if it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [1.0.4 Legendary Items preview](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923457/104_Legendary_Item_Improvements-8_14_2012), the caption below these boots say:

> Aside from looking really cool as it leaves a trail of fire behind you, this lets you create some interesting traps.

That implies that yes, the fire trail does do damage, and the mechanics behind it are probably exactly the same as the elite Molten affix.

As for the amount of damage these provide, I can find no information on that, but if this works just like Molten (which I believe is based on monster level), then it's going to provide a set amount of damage at level 60.  Paragon levels will almost certainly not affect it.

As an additional note, there are now affixes that increase fire damage by X%.  I do not believe the damage from the fire trail will benefit from these affixes.

Answer (score 0):

My boots definitely do damage from the trail. can't say the amount but it looks like its about half of what my normal attacks do, so im guess about 7000-8000. Who knows if its linked to weapon damage; level, crit, fire res, monster level, or just a flat rate but i promise you... monsters walk into my trail and they flash. health drops some even though no damage numbers appear. unless im witnessing thorn damage without the monster attacking.

Answer (score -3):

Fire walkers do NO damage from the fire left behind. The trail is PURELY COSMETIC. However it can trigger destructibles such as barrels. I am testifying from in-game experience using them. 
Now that said, I expected fire walkers to do damage as well. So I sold mine immediately before people start catching on to the fact that they do no damage.

Comment: This video clearly shows that you are incorrect.  http://da.twitch.tv/eightkilo/b/329519860